# Detect if nodes on a tree are directly connected

Tags: javascript, tree

There is a tree that looks like this:

[image]

User can select multiple nodes from a tree. I want to detect whether the selected nodes are directly connected. How to achieve that?

Here are some examples with a good selection:

[image]

and here are examples with a bad selection:

[image]

Here is the JSON data that I'm using

```
const tree = {
  id: "A",
  children: [
    {
      id: "B",
      children: [
        {
          id: "D",
          children: [
            {
              id: "E",
              children: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "C",
      children: [],
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: why is a single node a *good* selection? what have you tried?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, single node selections are considered as correct. My idea is to find the node with a lowest order level (so the top node), let's call it a root node. If there is more than one node we know that it's a sibling selection so it's considered as wrong. Then we need to find all of the possible paths from a root node to the end of the tree. When "going" through each path, we need to make sure that on all levels there is a node from our selection. If there is, we continue and remove the node from a selection array... Sounds complex :)

Comment: some examples with input and wanted output would make the question more clear. please add additionla information straight to the question instead using comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could distinguish these states that a tree could have with respect to the question:

- Clear: It has no selected node.
- Ongoing: It has a valid selection, and the root is part of it (so it could be extended in upward direction when this tree is a subtree of a larger tree).
- Completed: It has a valid selection, and the root is not part of it.
- Bad: It has an invalid selection.
- One: The root is selected, but information about the tree is not yet complete (temporary state).

We can derive this state from recursion, by doing a post-order traversal. So we would first determine the state of the child subtrees, and only then use that info for determining the (current) root's state. During the collection of states of the children, there can be a condition which immediately determines the root's state as "bad", and so recursion should immediately unwind.

Here is an implementation:

```js
"use strict";

const STATES = { CLEAR: 0, ONGOING: 1, COMPLETE: 2, BAD: 3, ONE: 4 };

function isPath(tree, selected) {
    let selectedSet = new Set(selected);
    
    function dfs(node) {
        let state = selectedSet.has(node.id) ? STATES.ONE : STATES.CLEAR;
        for (const child of node.children) {
            const childState = dfs(child);
            if (childState == STATES.CLEAR) continue;
            if (childState == STATES.BAD
                  || childState == STATES.COMPLETE && state != STATES.CLEAR
                  || childState == STATES.ONGOING && state == STATES.COMPLETE) return STATES.BAD;
            state = state == STATES.ONE ? STATES.ONGOING : STATES.COMPLETE;
        }
        return state == STATES.ONE ? STATES.ONGOING : state;
    }
    
    return [STATES.ONGOING, STATES.COMPLETE].includes(dfs(tree)) 
}

// Example run
const tree = {id: "A",children: [{id: "B",children: [{id: "D",children: [{id: "E",children: [],},],},],},{id: "C",children: [],},],};

console.log(isPath(tree, ["E","A"])); // false
console.log(isPath(tree, ["B","D"])); // true
console.log(isPath(tree, ["E"])); // true
console.log(isPath(tree, ["C","E"])); // false
console.log(isPath(tree, ["C","A","B"])); // true
```

Comment: Wooow, this looks very good- I think this is what I was looking for:) Thank you for the great explanation

Comment: I noticed it doesn't work when multiple children are selected. This case: `isPath(tree, ["A", "B", "C"])` -> `false`